# How to reach a restrserve api from rstudio server on aws?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, restrserve

I am trying out the very interesting package [RestRserve](https://github.com/rexyai/RestRserve) from with RStudo server that I installed on an AWS instance.

This is de code I use:

```
library(RestRserve)
app = Application$new()
app$add_get(
  path = "/hello", 
  FUN = function(request, response) {
    response$set_body("Hello from RestRserve")
  })
backend = BackendRserve$new()
backend$start(app, http_port = 8080)
```

I think the app is up and running, the message seems right:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-01-26 07:42:30.957686","level":"INFO","name":"Application","pid":1872,"msg":"","context":{"http_port":8080,"endpoints":{"HEAD":"/hello","GET":"/hello"}}}
-- running Rserve in this R session (pid=1872), 2 server(s) --
(This session will block until Rserve is shut down)
```

However, when I try to reach the app using the ip address of the instance like this: `http://35.180.45.129/hello` the browser says the site can't be reached.

Did I miss something? Any ideas about why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you need two additional steps:

- make sure you allow traffic from internet to 8080 port
- make sure you use public IP (or better DNS) of your instance

Comment: Thanks Dimitriy! I think I need to focus on your first remark. I will do some research.

Comment: But most of all, thank you for your brilliant package!